# How do I set a custom head for a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in the process of trying to replace a mob's head armor slot with a custom head.
The `/replaceitem` command doesn't seem to be working.

```
/replaceitem 
entity @e[name=Zombie] 
armor.head 
minecraft:player_head{
    Owner:{
        Id:"c6792fd4-414c-477f-8c2c-328df8569253",
        Properties:{
            textures:[{
Value: 
"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOTRlNTljNTQ3NmQ5ZTNhMjFjZTE2YmM1MWU2MThhNWVhMjQzN2IzNGU4MTJhZTBjYmExN2FiYWQyOGZlYTEyOSJ9fX0="
}]}}} 1
```

The head slot is replaced by a **regular** player head instead of the one I want.

Comment: The brackets seem unbalanced, as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's `SkullOwner` on items for some reason, not `Owner`. Also of course `@e[type=zombie]`, not `@e[name=Zombie]`, if you want to actually select all zombies instead of all entities named "Zombie" with a name tag.